# @ManyToOne hibernate mapping serialization

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I've got two SQL tables: users and teams with many-to-one relation and user_team table with FKs. I want to map this relation using hibernate. Before adding this relation everything was ok.

My stack trace:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with 
path [/gitsystem]   threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception 
is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause
    java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:328)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2912)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1673)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1605)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1505)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:943)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:911)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2238)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:549)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:95)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:107)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:593)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:572)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:527)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:507)
    at bg.glowacki.gitsystem.webapp.controller.AppController.listUsers(AppController.java:215)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

TeamEntity.java

```
package bg.glowacki.gitsystem.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;


@Entity
@Table(name="teams")
public class TeamEntity implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -7520338084244844389L;


private Long teamId;


private String name;

private UserEntity owner;

private String description;

private Set<UserEntity> members;

public TeamEntity() {
    super();
    members=new HashSet<UserEntity>();
}

public TeamEntity(String name, UserEntity owner) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.owner = owner;
    members=new HashSet<UserEntity>();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="teamid")
public Long getTeamId() {
    return teamId;
}

public void setTeamId(Long id) {
    this.teamId = id;
}

@Column(name="name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="owner")
public UserEntity getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(UserEntity owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}

@Column(name="description")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

 @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })  
 @JoinTable(name = "user_team", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "teamid") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "userid") })  
public Set<UserEntity> getMembers() {
    return members;
}

public void setMembers(Set<UserEntity> members) {
    this.members = members;
}




}
```

UserEntity.java

```
package bg.glowacki.gitsystem.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;


@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 333094694988498458L;

private Long userId;

private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private String login;

private String pass;

private String email;

private Set<TeamEntity> teams;

private List<String> permissions;

public UserEntity() {
    permissions=new ArrayList<String>();
    permissions.add("test");
    teams=new HashSet<TeamEntity>();
}

public UserEntity(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String login, String pass) {
    super();
    this.userId = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.login = login;
    this.pass = pass;
    teams=new HashSet<TeamEntity>();
}

public UserEntity(String firstName, String lastName, String login, String pass) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.login = login;
    this.pass = pass;
    teams=new HashSet<TeamEntity>();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="userid")
public Long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long id) {
    this.userId = id;
}

@Column(name="firstname")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Column(name="lastname")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Column(name="login",unique=true)
public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

@Column(name="pass")
public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}

@Column(name="email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "members")
public Set<TeamEntity> getTeams() {
    return teams;
}

public void setTeams(Set<TeamEntity> teams) {
    this.teams = teams;
}

@Transient
public List<String> getPermissions() {
    return permissions;
}

public void setPermissions(List<String> permissions) {
    this.permissions = permissions;
}

public String toString(){
    return "Login: "+login;
}

}
```

My tables:

users:

```
userid bigint (PK)
firstname text 
lastname text
login text
pass text
email text
```

teams:

```
teamid bigint (PK)
name text
owner bigint (FK to users)
description
```

user_team:

```
userid bigint (FK to users)
teamid bigint (FK to teams)
```

Problem must be somewhere in ManyToMany mapping, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Replace your `@JoinTable` annotation with this code:

```
@JoinTable(name = "user_team", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_to_teams_from_user_team", referencedColumnName = "teamid")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_to_users_from_user_team", referencedColumnName = "userid")})
```

Comment: could you post structures of your tables? users, teams and user_team

Comment: I guess the problem lies here:

    `@Column(name="owner")
    public UserEntity getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }`

You must set a relation on this getter! For example `@OneToOne`